# Storin a variable with many id's in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

```
var arrayOfId[] = $scope.rep.Selected.id;
```

I have this code. My question is if I had a some id's in `$scope`...Selected.id and then I make this (code) all these id's will be in every other array or in one array?

Comment: Your code will fire a SyntaxError

Comment: What is your scope?

Comment: My scope is a collection (json file) with names id etc

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.delIt = function () {
        if ($scope.rep.Selected > 0) {
            $scope.rep.Selected = true;
        } else {
            $scope.rep.Selected = false
        }

        var arrayOfId [] = $scope.rep.Selected.id;

        for(i=0; i<=arrayOfId[i]; i++){
            $http.delete("http://localhost:3000/users/" +arrayOfId[]); 
        }

}
```

This is full code. I wanted to send request every single id wich is stored in `$scope.rep.Selected.id`